# Unable to return list data from angular service to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to return some data from an angular service that calls a REST endpoint, however I can't seem to get the data flow right as it is asynchronous.

My service method.

```
   appService.getApplicationSupportFiles = function () {
        $http.post("/SEFlex/SEFlexAdmin/GetApplicationSupportFiles")
            .then(function (response, status, headers, config) {
                if (response.data) {
                    var list = JSON.parse(response.data.data);
                    return list;
                }
            });
    }
```

My controller

```
function ShowApplicationFilesController($scope, $http, $modalInstance, $log, SEApplicationService, $rootScope, AlertsService) {

    $rootScope.closeAlert = AlertsService.closeAlert;
    $scope.supportFiles = [];
    $scope.originalSupportFiles = [];
    $scope.isBusy = false;

    $scope.newFile = {
        localFile: "",
        cloudFile: "",
    }

    // Load the initial files
    $scope.supportFiles = SEApplicationService.getApplicationSupportFiles();
    $scope.originalSupportFiles = $scope.supportFiles;

    $scope.addApplicationFile = function() {
        var file = { LocalPath: $scope.newFile.localFile, ShareName: "b", FolderName: "c", FileName: "d" };
        $scope.supportFiles.push(file);
        $scope.newFile = { localFile: "", cloudFile: "" };
    }
}
```

The problem is the call to populate supportFiles is asynchronous so supportFiles is undefined when originalSupportFiles tries to copy the values. But also when I then click on addApplicationFile() it cannot push to the value $scope.supportFiles as it thinks it is undefined, so it looks like the values aren't getting loaded at all, even though the service gets called and returns data.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Look into `$q` and returning promises, you'll want to return a promise and use a .then() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return a promise and go from there - here's one way:

```
return $http.post("/SEFlex/SEFlexAdmin/GetApplicationSupportFiles").then(function (response, status, headers, config) {
    return response.data;
});
```

And then in your controller:

```
SEApplicationService.getApplicationSupportFiles().then(function(list) {
    $scope.supportFiles = list;
});
```

Comment: I've just tried changing my controller to what you suggested above (the service already uses .then as shown above - but I get the javascript error "0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference" in the controller.

Comment: @NZJames -- Your service doesnt return the `$http` request - it just returns the `data`.

Comment: That's what you had in your answer above though, returning response.data. Should the Service not have a .then() method?